# .htaccess mod_rewrite removing www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What this is trying to achieve is to re-write www.domain.com to domain.com, however I get the following server error,

> This webpage has a redirect loop

How do I solve this? I have tried various re-writes of the above and they all result in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somewhere, you already have a redirect somewhere that redirects from http://website.com to http://www.website.com (try it in your browser). It might be in your Apache configuration file.